# android- Convert Bitmap to matrix array

Tags: java, android, matlab, bitmap

I have MATLAB code that convert image to matrix array. Then it uses Zigzag reading operation in the conversion process from a multi-dimensional array to a one-dimensional array. Pseudo-code(MATLAB):

```
    array[M][N]=read_image(Image)
    array[1][MN]=zigzag(array[M][N])
```

I think I can use below code in JAVA to convert a Bitmap to byte array.

```
 // convert from bitmap to byte array
public byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

But I'm not sure. So is this way equals to MATLAB code or I must use another way ?

**Edit:** I also found these:

```
public int[][] getMatrixOfImage(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
int width = bufferedImage.getWidth(null);
int height = bufferedImage.getHeight(null);
int[][] pixels = new int[width][height];
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        pixels[i][j] = bufferedImage.getRGB(i, j);
    }
}

return pixels;
```

}

and also found this:

```
width = bitmap.getWidth();
height = bitmap.getHeight();

int size = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
byteArray = byteBuffer.array();
```

So which is the best way? Thanks anyway.

Comment: You get the bytes of a jpg file with your code. That is quite something different. You should better look at the Bitmap class to find what you want. `pixels`.

Comment: @blackapps okay I have edited the post. Could you look at the post please ?

Comment: CopyPixelsToBuffer i think. But you should decide what suits you best.